# Finding issue on Log4Net null reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, log4net

I'm running a strange issue using log4net (2.0.8) which is spamming "null references" exceptions

Once I've attached the pdb and browsed the source file if fall here (EventLogAppender.cs)

```
if (eventTxt.Length > MAX_EVENTLOG_MESSAGE_SIZE)
            {
                eventTxt = eventTxt.Substring(0, MAX_EVENTLOG_MESSAGE_SIZE);
            }
```

I've made a action break point and traced the value of eventTxt just it logs
"149"
However it enters in the if condition then throws an exception

here is a screenshot of visual
[image: Visual studio blocking on exception]
I suspect a code optimization to lead to a different reality than what i see.. Did I miss anything ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming (from the comments in the screenshot) that you already have the source for log4net. If so, why not compile in debug mode and that should avoid any optimisation issues.

Comment: good advice as real error camed from 2 lines below on the using of security context that was in fact null!

Answer (score 1):

optimization was leading me to false cause. Thanks to proposal of sgmoore I could check and find the actual exception source